# there is a strange thing happened in my grails controller, why?

Tags: grails, controller

my enviroment:

```
java version "1.6.0_38"
Grails 2.1.1
grails create-app test
cd test<br>
grails create-controller com.test.Test
```

There is **NO SPECIAL CONFIG** in `UrlMapping`.

`com.test.TestController`:

```
package com.test

class TestController {
    def getA(){
        def ret = []
        println "in getA"
        render ret
    }

    def index() { 
        println "in index"
        render view:"index"

    }
}
```

grails-app/test/index.gsp:

```
<html>
 <body> hello  </body>
</html>
```

when i try to access [ `http://HOSTNAME/PRJNAME/test/index` ]
i suppose that would happend:
HTML: 
<html>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>

Console : 
in index

BUT,things not like that, actually, it's like this:
HTML: 
[]<html>
<body>
hello
</body>
</html>

Console : 
in index
in getA

Why??

Comment: this is really weird, i can just say that inside the gsp the body must be closed inside the html tag ^^

Comment: oh, that's my fault, i paste it by mistake. T_T||  Fix it now..

Comment: does it still occur when you create a domain class for Test?   console -> create-domain-class [test]

Comment: i didn't try this, but when i modified the name 'getA' to 'listA' or something else without the word 'get', that works fine.

Comment: i just run `grails create-domain-class com.test.Test`, there's no help.

Answer (score 1):

Grails calls all methods that start with "get" to find closures that are used as actions. Since the syntax `def foo = { ... }` defines a closure as a property, Groovy adds a getter and setter (`getFoo` and `setFoo`), so the closures are discovered by finding properties and calling the getters to check if the return type is a Closure. Since controllers are (by default) prototype scoped they're created for each request, each public getter method gets called for each request.

So the workaround is to not start action methods with "get".

Comment: thx a lot,that sounds right, but when i modify the action 'index' to
`def index() { println "in index";render "hello index!";}`
it will work rightly.
my question is : why 'getA' was called when `render view:'index'`, and not called when `render 'hello index!'`. what's the diff?

Comment: Wow, thank you!  I thought I was going crazy, my controller was running all my actions.  I was cutting everything up, trying to figure out why this was happening.  Lesson learned!